# Cannot use instanceof on union type in typescript

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, union, instanceof

I get the error:

> TS2358: The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of
>   type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.

When compiling the following code:

```
const animal: Tiger | Monkey | Goat = fetchAnimal();
if (!animal instanceof Tiger && !animal instanceof Monkey) {
    alert('It is safe to touch the animal');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add parenthesis, then it worked:

```
if (!(animal instanceof Tiger) && !(animal instanceof Monkey)) {
    alert('It is safe to touch the animal');
}
```

Comment: Yes. Without the `()`, it's `(!animal) instanceof Monkey` which ends up being `true instanceof Monkey` or `false instanceof Monkey`. :-) Unary operators are typically **very** high precedence.